# left strip anything before the second number in a string

Tags: python

```
a = "some rubish 2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 4377435"
```

This is some address string with some extra information I want to strip everything before the street number which is always the 2nd number from the right. I want output as

```
"2403 some street address, TX 4377435"
```

Till now I could come up with this

```
special_char = '!@#$%^&*()-_=+,./\\;:<>?{}[]|    '
ascii_letters  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
a = "some rubish 2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 77630409"
a.lstrip(ascii_letters+special_char)
```

Which gives output

```
2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 77630409
```

Comment: is the first number always 1 digit? (is the address always more than 1 digit)

Comment: Yes, in the output the first thing should be a number. There will be minimum 2 numbers

Comment: So you could just use a regex like [``\d\d+.*``](https://regexr.com/60s2p)?

Comment: @Sayse no the numbers can be of any size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a regex splitting option.  We can split the input string at any space which is followed by a digit (using a lookahead to avoid consuming that digit).  Then, splice off the first two elements and retain the rest.  Finally, join back to a single string by reintroducing the space.

```py
a = "some rubish 2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 4377435"
parts = re.split(r'[ ](?=\d)', a)
print(' '.join(parts[2:]))  # 2403 some street address, TX 4377435
```

Comment: Your answer is very clever, but you can improve it with `maxsplit` argument `parts = re.split(r'[ ](?=\d)', a, 2)` so you can use `parts[-1]` and not needed to join string back. Also it won't throw an exception in case if there's no match of expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the index of the second number from the right using `re` and `[-2]` index and slice the string by it

```
a = "some rubish 2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 4377435"
index = re.findall(r"\d+", a)[-2]
print(a[a.index(index):]) # 2403 some street address, TX 77630409
```

Comment: It's slightly better to use `finditer()` to not let program search for each occurrence of number but stop on second match *(if exist)*. It's easy to apply [`Match.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) on [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) `[m.start() for m in islice(re.finditer(r"\d+", a), 2)]`. Then just use `a[matches[-1] if len(matches) == 2 else None:]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re    

re.search("\d\d+.*","some rubish 2 some more rubish 2403 some street address, TX 77630409 asdsad").group()
```